# Sumar valor de Inputs en React js de forma dinamica

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks

Estoy aprendiendo React, mi intención es crear 3 inputs de tipo numero y un cuarto el cual muestra la sumatoria total de los anteriores en tiempo real.

Logro mostrar la sumatoria total pero al momento de cambiar el valor de un input, la sumatoria total sigue incrementando teniendo en cuenta los valores anteriores.

```
<input type='number' onChange={ e => setResultado(resultado + parseFloat(e.target.value))}/>
```

Luego probe crear un useState para cada input de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type='number' value={input1} onChange={ e => setInput1(parseFloat(e.target.value))}/>
```

pero en esta ultima no logro mostrar la sumatoria en tiempo real, ¿podría ser utilizadon un useEffect?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow, te aconsejo que hagas un [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que entiendas como es que funciona stackoverflow, lee [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que puedas elaborar una buena pregunta asi puedo ayudarte

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida, ahi redacte lo mas claro posible!

Comment: .@EzequielGonzalez, adjunta el código del componente completo, o al menos un ejemplo mínimio reproducible, @Enzo ya proporciono las ligas donde puedes revisar estas recomendaciones. Saludos

Comment: a ver si entiendo, tu intencion es tener 3 input de tipo `number` y mediante vas cambiando el valor el 4to input refleja la suma total de los 3 ? es asi ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo de la pregunta que hiciste es que estas teniendo 3 inputs de tipo `number` y un 4 input que refleja la suma de los 3 inputs, prepare ese ejemplo

```
export default function App() {

  const [number, setNumber] = useState({one: 0, two: 0, three: 0})
  const [suma, setSuma] = useState()

  useEffect(()=>{
    const { one, two, three } = number
    setSuma(Number(one) + Number(two) + Number(three))
  },[number])

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target
    setNumber({...number, [name]: value})
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input className="input" onChange={handleInput} name="one" value={number.one} placeholder="Ingesa un numero (1)"/>
      <input className="input" onChange={handleInput} name="two" value={number.two} placeholder="Ingesa un numero (2)"/>
      <input className="input" onChange={handleInput} name="three" value={number.three} placeholder="Ingesa un numero (3)"/>
      <input value={suma}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

paso a explicar como es que funciona esta porción de código, el `hook` `number` contiene un objeto con los valores de los 3 principales inputs, el `hook` `suma` es el que contiene la suma de los 3 inputs, la funcion `handleInput` es la que controla los 3 inputs principales, desde el `event.target` destructuro el campo `name` y el campo `value`, el campo name es el atributo `name` de los inputs, entonces lo que hago es actualizar el valor del `hook` `number`, como es un objeto, lo que hago es decirle que va a seguir teniendo el mismo valor con un simple `...number` y luego hago uso del name como clave para actualizar solamente ese campo sin alterar los demas, y utilizo el value para asignarle el nuevo valor, luego hago uso del `useEffect` para actualizar el `hook` `suma` cada vez que el `hook` `number` cambie, destructuro el `hook` `number`, y luego prosigo con la suma, utilizo el constructor `Number` para poder sumar los numero ya que js no sabe que por defecto es un numero y de no utilizar el constructor este mismo se concatenarían y no sumarian, espero que hayas entendido mas o menos por donde va la mano, te dejo un [ejemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-mountain-sjygz?file=/src/App.js:68-911) para que puedas interactuar con el código, saludos